# using filter in Python 3

Tags: python

I am pretty much copying from the example given in online docs, but using filter() in windows-based Python 3 is perplexing me.  What is wrong here:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]    
b=[1,0,1,0]    
f=filter(b,a)    
for fs in f : print(fs)

...
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>       TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

```
f=list(filter(b,a))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>       TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Online docs say to throw `list()` in, but that clearly helps not.

Comment: What output do you expect to get here? Note that `filter` is not the same thing as "find the elements in these lists that are in both lists"

Comment: What online docs are you referring to? The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) do not say "to throw list() in".

Comment: Which online docs are you referring to? Is `b` meant to indicate which values in `a` you want and don't want, i.e. is `b` a mask on `a`?

Answer (score 1):

First argument of `filter` must be a function or lambda. You passed `b` which is a list.

Comment: Isn't `lambda` a function (anonymous)?

Comment: @AChampion yes it is. I mentioned it separately just to emphasize it.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how `filter` works, `filter` needs a function that returns `True` for each item that you want to keep.

I'm assuming `b` describes the things in `a` you want to select, then you meant something like::

```
f = filter(lambda x: x[1], zip(a, b))
for fs, _ in f: ...
```

You can also replace `filter` with a list comprehension:

```
f = [x for x, y in zip(a, b) if y]
for fs in f: ...
```

But there is a function in `itertools` that does exactly this:

```
import itertools as it
f = it.compress(a, b)
for fs in f: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter's documentation clearly states that it takes a function and an iterable as input. Perhaps if you want to check if a value is in both a and b, you could do something like:

```
f = filter(lambda x: x in b, a)
```

and then loop over f.

Answer (score 0):

Basically filter takes a function and an iterable value to filter in

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,0,1,0]
f = filter(lambda val: val not in b, a)
for fs in f: print(fs)
```

output:

```
2
3
4
```

Confusion occurs when we call filter with None

```
list(filter(None, [0,1,2]))
# This returns [1,2] Which is a special case
# and it is not equal to:
list(filter(1, [0,1,2])) #invalid
```

The reason being When we pass filter condition as `None` filter function checks each value in the list and sees if they qualify the `if value` condition.

Which roughly translates to this.

```
[value for value in [0,1,2] if value]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to understand.  I am always curious why Python doesn't provide the 'obvious' solution as the base case, and a more complex one for the more rich case...in this case, it seems to me (and I saw many wrong examples) that filter([1,0,1,0], [2,4,6,8]) ought to return a list (or in Python three a generator) that gives back (appropriately for the version) 2 and 6 as the answer - i.e., a mask.

Comment: Were it me making the calls, 'filter' would just use a mask, and something called ffilter or some such would require the lambda...the lambda seems like both unnecessary keystrokes, unnecessary function calls, and buggy/cryptic code.

Comment: @eSurfsnake not sure about the design reason for the filter API. But anyways, glad I could clarify the problem :). Please consider upvote or tick, if the answer helped :)